# Set Bootstrap current tab on reload snippet not storing last tab in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set the current tab (last one viewed before page reload) when the page loads. I have tried multiple solutions on stackoverflow with no success.

```
$(function() { 
  //for bootstrap 3 use 'shown.bs.tab' instead of 'shown' in the next line
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    //save the latest tab; use cookies if you like 'em better:
    localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(e.target).attr('id'));
  });

  //go to the latest tab, if it exists:
  var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
  if (lastTab) {
      $('#'+lastTab).tab('show');
  }
}


);
```

And here is my tab HTML

```
<div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#all" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#this_month" data-toggle="tab">This Month</a></li>
    <li><a href="#next_month" data-toggle="tab">Next Month</a></li>
    <li><a href="#last_month" data-toggle="tab">Last Month</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="all">
      <%= render partial: 'layouts/format_bills', locals: { bill_filter: @all_bills_by_months } %>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="this_month">
      <%= render partial: 'layouts/format_bills', locals: { bill_filter: @bills_for_this_month } %>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="next_month">
      <%= render partial: 'layouts/format_bills', locals: { bill_filter: @bills_for_next_month } %>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="last_month">
      <%= render partial: 'layouts/format_bills', locals: { bill_filter: @bills_for_last_month } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(For the bug mentioned in the below comments only)

```
  function setLatestTab() {
    var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
    if (lastTab) {
      $('a[href='+lastTab+']').click();
    } 
  }

  setLatestTab();
  $('.table #payBills').on('click', function(e) {
    setLatestTab();
  });
```

Doesn't set the latest tab after clicking the link.

And the Pay action:

```
  def pay 
      @bill.update_attributes(paid: true)
      redirect_to bills_path
  end
```

Comment: what _does_ happens when you run this code?

Comment: It just tabs like normal and doesn't save the tab on reload. Also the lastTab localStorage variable stays undefined.

Comment: It was undefined because your selector was not accurate

Comment: ["Sometimes inexperienced developers think of redirect_to as a sort of goto command, moving execution from one place to another in your Rails code."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect-to) _it is obvious that no DOM events are triggered using redirect_to_, then the dom ready scripts naturally will not be executed. So you need another approach, like the one you use in delete, which seems to work. If you reload after pay, it is also showing the right tab, which is another proof. But nothing of this have anything to do with my answer at all.

Comment: Yes, I realized it wasn't any thing to do with your answer. I asked you because you seemed to be the guy for the job. I have fixed the problem. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with your markup :

```
$(function() { 
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var tab = $(this).attr('href');
    localStorage.setItem('lastTab', tab);
  });

  //go to the latest tab, if it exists:
  var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
  if (lastTab) {
    $('a[href='+lastTab+']').click();
  }
}
```

I struggled a lot with `tab('show')` - it does not seem to work, not even hardcoded the way the [api 3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) suggest. It worked back in the good old 2.3.x days. It would not be the first time, though, an anomaly or "feature" is discovered in bootstrap.

Comment: It's working, thanks! One little bug (http://billpay.herokuapp.com/) though. I need it to reload on the tab again when I click the "Pay" or "delete" button. I've updated my post with the method I have tried.

Comment: It is not a "bug". `Pay` obviously is a link that does something and then reloads the page - your _altered_ code, `setLatestTab();` inside click is _never_ executed after page reload. Simply keep the code as I demonstrated, in a `$(function() {` where it will be executed each time the page reloads.

Comment: It's a script that reloads the page when changes to files are made. Pretty much functions like a "live view". I forgot to only include that in development. I updated my post to include the Pay action.